# Cannot use parentheses when calling a sub vb

Tags: vbscript, parentheses

First things first, I've had a look on similar issues on the site but can't spot the error of my ways.

I'm also new to vb so this too does not help.

Please help out a real novice...

Thanks

```
dim profileSize
dim oFS, oFolder
set oFS = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
strUserName = wshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "%USERNAME%" )
set oFolder = oFS.GetFolder("\\burns\Profiles\" + strUserName + ".V2")

ShowFolderDetails oFolder

sub ShowFolderDetails(oF)
dim F
    profileSize = of.Size
    if profileSize > 1006582400 Then    
    WriteFileText(profileSize, strUserName)
    End If
    if profileSize > 2516582400 Then    
    WriteFileText(profileSize, strUserName)
    wscript.echo "Your Windows user profile is too big! Please contact the IT Office"
    WScript.Quit
    End if

    for each F in oF.Subfolders
    'ShowFolderDetails(F)
    next
end sub


sub WriteFileText(sText, userID)
    Dim objFSO 'As FileSystemObject
    Dim objTextFile 'As Object
    strLogFilePath = "\\burns\Profiles\size_log.txt"
    strTime = FormatDateTime(Date(), 0)
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const ForWriting = 2
    Const ForAppending = 8

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strLogFilePath, ForAppending, True)

    ' Write a line.
    objTextFile.WriteLine (strTime + "," + userID + "," + sText )

    objTextFile.Close
    'objTextFile.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: What is your question? Where do you have problems? What is the error? What would you expect? What have you tried? Have you read [How do I ask good questions?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 5):

The error message "Cannot use parentheses when calling a Sub" means that you cannot use parentheses when calling a sub ;-).

In VBA you use parenthesis for the function call if:

1. The function call has an assignment to the return value.
2. You have an argument-list and use the 'call' keyword.

So you should be able to call your sub like this:

```
WriteFileText x,y
```

or, if you insists on having the parenthesis:

```
call WriteFileText (x, y)
```

Comment: See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) for further details.